# Can I filter on a nested field as fast as on a top-level field?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am not sure how to optimize table schema when using nested structs.

Imagine I have a table in BigQuery with the following schema:

```
USER
firstName: string
lastName: string
accountID: string
posts: [
    {
     title: string
     body: string
     postID: string
    }
]
```

If I want to SELECT users who have a post with title = "Hello World!", will it be a much slower query than SELECTing users whose firstName = "Jose"? In other words, do I lose the speed benefits of columnar storage if I query a nested value?

Would it be better to create a separate table for each type of query? In other words, have a User table with nested Posts when I want to filter by the User's top level attributes, and also have a Post table with nested Users when I want to filter by Post attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I want to SELECT users who have a post with title = "Hello World!", will it be a much slower query than SELECTing users whose firstName = "Jose"?

No, it will not be much slower. Both will be equally slow. But please note: slow is quite relative notion - what one would consider fast - other would consider slow and vice verse. If you are looking for subseconds - BigQuery is not your choice! But if you are looking for seconds - you will get it and you will definitely enjoy power of BigQuery

> In other words, do I lose the speed benefits of columnar storage if I query a nested value?

You actually leverage speed of columnar storage here, even for nested values

> Would it be better to create a separate table for each type of query?

No, it will not be better - ideally (with BigQuery) you should keep your data as denormalized as you can.   Obviously it is still up to you to have some level of normalization but cost of it will be JOINs performance and cost of redundantly stored data

Comment: I understand that values of a given column are stored sequentially in BQ, hence the speedy read of a single column. How are nested structs stored on disk? Are they essentially object by object, or are the objects also stored by column?

Comment: @NicoCernek - there are number of articles on that topic  - this is one of them - [Inside Capacitor, BigQuery’s next-generation columnar storage format](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/inside-capacitor-bigquerys-next-generation-columnar-storage-format)

Comment: The Capacitor article led me to the Dremel paper (page 3)  which describes nested structs as boing stored by column. https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/36632.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation :

```
select
  *
from
  USER
where
  exists(select 1 from unnest(posts) where title = 'Hello World!')
```

Comparison : 
Filtering in nested structure is faster than creation of another POST table. This kind of strategy is also called `denormalized table`, you can check link below

[Denormalization](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/bigquery-data-warehouse#managing_data)

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the type of database, when filtering through a nested field (even in a columnar db system like BigQuery) you are essentially issuing an `UNNEST` statement to do any filtering from within the nested column. This means that you will be *at least* performing `n x m` operations (where `n` is number of rows and `m` is number of fields in your nested column).

For instance, to run your desired query, you will have to do:

```
select * from `mydataset.USERS`, unnest(posts) as x
where x.title = "Hello World!"
```

This being said, yes, the ideal way to have your data managed in a relational database system is to structure it accordingly. In your case you can always save the `posts` in a separate table, which can have the following structure:

```
select accountID, x.postID, x.title, x.body
from `mydataset.USERS`, UNNEST(posts) as x
```

And then use `JOIN` to get your desired data:

```
select U.accountID, P.postID, P.title, P.body
from `mydataset.USERS` U 
join `mydataset.posts` P on U.accountID = P.accountID
where P.title = "Hello World!"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: To confirm: You say that UNNEST requires a scan of the whole nested object, so if I'm understanding correctly, nested values in BQ are stored on disk object by object, and not split across columns. Therefore you lose the benefits of columnar storage?

Comment: I do not know the internals of nested objects in BigQuery to be honest. However, as per documentation: `UNNEST` function is used to flatten an array. This logically explains that you have to flatten a set of elements before querying them, so, you still probably end up doing `n x m`. However, it really depends on the implementation of that flattening operation (which I believe is a very highly parallelized operation on the BQ backend). For the speed differences, I don't think its a straight forward approximation given massively parallelized nature of BigQuery.

Comment: According to the Dremel paper (page 3), nested structs are also stored by column. Not sure how this informs query time. https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/36632.pdf